# How do I stream my microphone via VLC?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, vlc

I'm sure this is a quick one if you know it but I'm stuck been searching around for a long while now.

All AUDIO works mic/Spkers/Skype etc... which is great.

What I am trying to do is get the mic to stream via VLC but for that I need to know the device as in `/dev/video0` (webcam) but what is the same for the Mic In on the sound card and how do i find that out ?

Under Sound Preferences >> Input its listed under Internal Audio Analogue Stereo (Rear Microphone)

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                  HDA Intel at 0xf9ffc000 irq 44
 1 [HD5001         ]: USB-Audio - Microsoft® LifeCam HD-5001
                  Microsoft Microsoft® LifeCam HD-5001 at usb-0000:00:1d.7-6.2.4,high speed



aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the settings I used in VLC's "Open Capture Device" dialog on my MacBook 2,1 running Ubuntu 11.04:

- Capture mode: `Video for Linux 2`
- Video: `/dev/video0`
- Audio: `plughw`

If you're doing a desktop capture or something like that and would like to add microphone audio to it, you'll have to check "show more options" -> "play another media file synchronously" and enter the entire URI which is: `alsa://plughw`

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!! I have been trying for a long while to get this to work =))

Answer (score 3):

I know this was a long time ago but I used this VLC command to stream my USB mic as RTSP.

You might need find your mics device id. Mine is 1,0. 
Use arecord -l to see.

From the server

```
vlc -vvv alsa://plughw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:rtp{dst=192.168.1.121,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://192.168.1.121:8080/test.sdp}'
```

From the client

```
vlc rtsp://192.168.1.121:8080/test.sdp
```

Comment: I was searching so long for this command and this is the only one which has worked thanks!